# Библиотека-СУБД на Java?

Tags: java, база-данных

Суть вопроса заключается в возможности хранения данных для последующего использования с возможностью выборки, фильтрации.
В Java есть возможность взаимодействия с СУБД посредством драйвера и JDBC. При этом такая СУБД является внешним компонентом и не интегрирована в Java.
Хотелось бы узнать, есть ли возможность использовать какую-то библиотеку или фреймворк в своём проекте, непосредственно осуществляющую роль СУБД?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да есть. Загуглите java база данных H2. В spring boot  удобно работать с ней, там она легко [подключается](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database). Ну то есть это полноценная реляционная база данных встроенная в ваше приложение

Comment: дополню, все библиотеки также доступны в https://mvnrepository.com для подключения в конфиг-файлах maven-gradle
h2
hsqldb
sqlite

примеры также можно найти.

Comment: Список огромен. Derby( Cloudscape),  coucbase,  и  пр.

Comment: Я ток с H2 работал, поэтому другие и  не рекомендую

Comment: Всё отлично! Я попробовал H2 и это то, что нужно! Спасибо!